where is MinGW-W64 installed under macOS using ports? Is there a script to setup the environment?
I installed MinGW-W64 to cross compile and build Windows executables under macOS, using
sudo port install x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
It worked flawlessly (macOS BigSur here).
Where are the binary and libs installed?
To find it out I typed sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb .
After that I was able to do a locate mingwand found out, it is in
$ ls /opt/local/x86_64-w64-mingw32
bin host    include lib lib32
$ cd bin
ls | grep gcc
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-14.1.0
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib




To find libraries try something like locate libkernel32.a
